# Rewrite Rule Confusion

Tags: apache, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Not sure if I'm doing something silly here or not, but the first rewrite rule works fine but the second one isn't doing anything, the first rule is always applied, from what I can see the syntax is correct, could it be the ampersand in the second rule between the `$2` and `$3` values?

URL:

```
/activate/activate/?e=testemail@localhost.com&c=123456
```

Rules:

```
RewriteRule ^activate/([^/]*)/$ /activate.php?sa=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^activate/([^/]*)/?e=([^/]*)&c=([^/]*)$ /activate.php?sa=$1&e=$2&c=$3 [NC,L]
```

EDIT:

Tired using the query string to resolve the problem but doesn't seem to be working, I'm pretty sure I've got it the wrong way around!?

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^sa=([^/]*)&e=([^/]*)&c=([^/]*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/([^/]*)/?e=([^/]*)&c=([^/]*)$ /activate.php?sa=$1&e=$2&c=$3 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Have to test the query with QUERY_STRING

Comment: @FelipeAlamedaA, I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: Testing the query in the rewrite rule regex (`?e=([^/]*)&c=([^/]*)`) is not possible. Have to add a previous condition to test it. i.e. `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} e=([^/]*)&c=([^/]*)`. The groups () captured in the conditions can be used in the rewrite rule using %n instead of $n.

Comment: @FelipeAlamedaA, i get you now, something like the edit in the OT, any suggestions as to where I'm going wrong, can't seem to get it working?